# Real Time Workaround using windows for fixed sampling time

Tags: windows, matlab, real-time, frequency, sampling

I am trying to collect data off an accelerometer sensor. I have an Arduino doing the analog to digital conversion of the signal and sending it through a serial port to MATLAB on Windows.

I send a reading every 5ms from the Arduino through the serial port. I am saving that data using MATLAB's serial read in a vector as well as the time at which it was read using the clock method.

If I was to plot the column of the vector where I have saved at which second I read, I get a curve (non-linear), and when I look at the difference between 1 read and another, I see that it is slightly varying.

Is there any way to get the data saved in real time with fixed sampling time?

Note: *I am using 250000 baud rate.*

Matlab Code:

```
    %%%%% Initialisation %%%%%
clear all
clc
format shortg

cnt = 1;%File name changer
sw = 1;%switch: 0 we add to current vector and 1 to start new vector
%%%%% Initialisation %%%%%

%%%%% Communication %%%%%
arduino=serial('COM7','BaudRate',250000);
fopen(arduino);
%%%%% Communication %%%%%

%%%%% Reading from Serial and Writing to .mat file%%%%%
while true,
    if sw == 0,
        if (length(Vib(:,1))==1000),% XXXX Samples in XX minutes
            filename = sprintf('C:/Directory/%d_VibrationReading.mat',cnt);
            save (filename,'Vib');
            clear Vib
            cnt= cnt+1;
            sw = 1;
        end
    end
    scan = fscanf(arduino,'%f');
    if isfloat(scan) && length(scan(:,1))==6,% Change length for validation
        vib = scan';
        if sw == 1,
            Vib = [vib clock];
            sw = 0;
        else
            Vib = [Vib;vib clock];
        end
    end
end
%%%%% Reading from Serial and Writing to .mat file%%%%%

% Close Arduino Serial Port
fclose(arduino);
```

Image 1 shows the data received through serial (each Row corresponding to 1 serial read)
Image 2 shows that data saved with the clock

Image 1:
[image]

Image 2:
[image]

Comment: Please put your code and the measurements into your question. You won't reach a perfect precision because MATLAB is not capable of real time processing, but the curve should be (roughly) linear.

Comment: I have added the code, I did some research on the real-time topic, and saw that there is a toolbox in matlab that dedicates a kernel just for reading data from some "specific" devices like National Instruments Data acquisition tools, i dont know much about how they do it but apparently there must be a way around that, hopefully a lot simpler. By the way if your sampling frequency gets lower i saw that Matlab was somewhat able to handle that, however i need a high sampling rate so that wont cut it for me

Comment: That line `length(scan(:,1))==6` potentially drops messages, when your system is slow it may receive two messages at once.

Comment: yes but this was the only way (i found) to make sure am not reading wrong characters due to serial communication

Comment: Can you put an example message you receive into the question? My guess is you are already exceeding the baud rate available. How many chars are used for each number?

Comment: I have added 2 images that show the data, please note i tried going down to only 3 sensors, e.g. of read (332 334 332) however the delay i put in arduino before sending the data through serial (the 5ms delay) is the cause of the problem i guess, since if i increase that to 50ms, Matlab seems to be ale to better handle the data received

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I know that my answer does not contain a quick and easy solution. Instead it primarily gives advice how to redesign your system. I worked with real-time systems for several years and saw it done wrong too many time. It might be possible to just "fix", but working with your current communication pattern tweaking the performance but I am convinced you will never receive reliable time information.*

I will answer this from a general system design perspective, instead of trying to fix your code. Where I see the problems:

1. In general, it is a bad idea to append time information on the receiving PC. Whenever the sensor is capable and has a clock, append the time information on the sensor system itself. This allows for an accurate relative timing between the measurements. Some clock adjustment might be necessary when the clock on the sensor is not set properly, but that is just a constant offset.
2. Switch from ASCII-encoded data to binary data. With your sample rate and baut rate set, you only have 50 bytes for each message.
3. Write a robust receiver. Just dropping messages you "don't understand" is not a good idea. Whenever the buffer is full, you might receive multiple messages unless you use a proper terminator.
4. Use preallocation. You know how large the batches you want to write are.

A simple solution for a message:

```
2 bytes - clock milliseconds
4 bytes - unix timestamp of measurement
For each sensor
    2 bytes int32 sensor data
2 bytes - Terminator, constant value. Use a value which is outside the range for all previous integers, e.g. intmax
```

This message format should theoretically allow you to use 21 sensors. Now to the receiving part:

To get a first version running with a good performance, call `fread (serial)` with large batches of data (`size` parameter) and dump all readings into a large cell array. Something like:

```
C=cell(1000,1)
%seek until you hit a terminator
while not(terminator==fread(arduino,1));
for ix=1:numel(C)
    C{ix}=fread(arduino,'int16',1000)
end
fclose(arduino);
```

Once you read the data append it to a single vector: `C=[C{:}];` and try to parse it in post-processing. If you manage the performance you may later return to on-the-fly processing, but I recommend to start this way to get the system established.

Comment: Daniel thanks a lot for the answer, what you are saying sounds a good way to optimize the design so am going to implement that